# CasperJS - Continue on step timeout

Tags: javascript, casperjs

As the title says, how can I make casperjs execute next step if previous step time-out?

My current code:

```
var casper =  require('casper').create({

    stepTimeout: 30000,
    verbose: true,
    onError: function(self, m) {   // Any "error" level message will be written
        console.log('FATAL:' + m); // on the console output and PhantomJS will
        self.exit();               // terminate
    },
});
```

I know there is an option [`onStepTimeout`](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.options).

> A function to be executed when a step function execution time exceeds
>   the value of the stepTimeout option, if any has been set.
>
> By default, on timeout the script will exit displaying an error,
>   except in **test environment** where it will just add a failure to the
>   suite results.

Or in other words, how can I enter the "test environment"? Can't find anything related to environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can give your self-answer the tick. The "test environment" refers to use casper with the Tester module: http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html

Answer (score 3):

oh, I think I'm just stupid...............

```
var casper =  require('casper').create({

    stepTimeout: 30000,
    verbose: true,
    onError: function(self, m) {   // Any "error" level message will be written
        console.log('FATAL:' + m); // on the console output and PhantomJS will
        self.exit();               // terminate
    },
    onStepTimeout(self,m){
       console.log('timeout: step' + m);
    }
});
```